# AngularJS animate when appending a row to the table

Tags: angularjs, animation

I am appending a new row to a table. Its working fine. But When its appending I need to implement it with ease in animation functionality. Tell me how should I implement this.

```
 $scope.addRow=function(){
        var $el = $('<td contenteditable><input type="text" class="editBox" value=""/></td>' +
                '<td contenteditable><input type="text" class="editBox" value=""/></td>' +
                '<td>' +
                '<span>' +
                '<button id="createHost" class="btn btn-mini btn-success" data-ng-click="create()"><b>Create</b></button>' +
                '</span>' +
                '</td>').appendTo('#newTransaction');
        $compile($el)($scope);  
    };
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing something like this in your controller. You should avoid manipulating the DOM unless you're writing a directive. This seems to be a good use case for ng-repeat and binding to an array. Using ng-repeat with animations is easy.
Read up on some Angular best practices or find some sample projects. It's tough to wrap your head around at first.

Comment: @Adam: Actually I have implemented with a template using factory and directives, but to post here its very big. So can u help me out with this example?? I will make necessary changes with my code